# Question about composition Little-o

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Recall that $f(x)=o(x^n)$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^n}=0$

In a test, I was given two functions: the first one is $\sin x$, the second is a function $g(x)$ whose Taylor polynomial is given by $2+2x^2-\frac52x^3+\frac{1}{15}x^4$. The question was to find a Taylor expression of $g(\sin(x^2))$ using a Taylor polynomial and a remainder expressed by $o(x^4)$.

I know that $\sin(x^2)=x^2+o(x^2)$ and from the given about the Taylor polynomial I can conclude that $g(x)=2+2x^2+o(x^2)$, now, I have no idea how to proceed, since I don't know how to compose two functions expressed with little-o, on one another, but the answer is $g(\sin(x^2))=2+2x^4+o(x^4)$ so I assume that I need to compose the polynomials on another and separately compose the little-o's on one another, but I have no idea why that would be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can proceed as

$$
g(\sin(x^2)) = 2 + 2\underbrace{\sin^2(x^2)}_{x^4 + o(x^4)} - \frac{5}{2} \underbrace{\sin^3(x^2)}_{o(x^4)} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{15} \sin^4(x^2)}_{o(x^4)} = 2 + 2x^4 + o(x^4).
$$

In the picture the blue curve is $g(\sin(x^2))$ and the green curve is $h(x) = 2+2x^4$

[image]